# GKE No cluster named 'cluster-1' in project-id

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Missing clusters after resolving GCP billing.

- Gcp project had unresolved billing.
- This led to instances and k8 resources unaccessible.
- We resolved the billing.
- All instances and (k8) instance groups came back.

Problem the clusters are nowhere to be seen.

```
gcloud container clusters list
*empty*
```

Before this we had services running.

All loadbalancers are visible under `network services`

How do I rebuild the cluster from the instances?

Comment: Hi there! Normally services can take some time to be reconciled once a valid  billing account was attached to the project. I think your best chance is to contact Google Cloud Support so they can help you with this.

Comment: Are you sure to request the correct project? Can you add a `--project=<PROJECT-ID>` with your project ID at the end of the gcloud command?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes I have.
Checked on gcp `web console ->kubernetes->clusters` as well

Answer (score 0):

By any chance was the unresolved billing related to the end of the GCP free trial?

If this was the case, if this was less than 30 days, there is still a good chance of getting your clusters back. Since at then end of the free trial all services are stopped and sent for deletion, as [outlined here.](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end) But there is a [grace period of 30 days](https://cloud.google.com/security/deletion#deletion_timeline) so these services can be recovered

If this is still before the 30 days, and you have upgraded to a paid GCP plan and the clusters have not showed up, I would indeed recommend to [contact GCP support](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#support) to see what is going on